# How to set up DNS records / domain files on aplus.net for a custom domain for Heroku?

Tags: domains, dns, heroku

Aplus.net is not [listed as one of the DNS providers by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) for setting up a custom domain for your Heroku app. And you can't delete the default A record for your domain. How can you configure Aplus.net to use your domain for your heroku app?

Answer (score 3):

Although you cannot delete the A record for apex domain, Aplus.net does allow for CNAME-based aliasing.

First, [generate the dns target for the www subdomain in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain), e.g. `whispering-willow-5678.herokudns.com`.

Then, in the Aplus.net control panel for the domain,

- delete the A `www` record
- create a CNAME `www` record with the Heroku dns target (include a period at the end, e.g. `whispering-willow-5678.herokudns.com.`)
- create a CNAME `*` record with the same target
- go to the Forwarding tab, set Global Redirection to "mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com", and hit Save

Then wait for the changes to propagate. If there are still issues, you may also need to ask support to change your bare A record to point to a different internal IP address.

Comment: In other words, you are pointing the www record to Heroku via CNAME and Aplus redirect the domain apex and all other subdomains to the www subdomain.

Comment: exactly. I expect this method works with other domain providers with similar set ups, this is just the one I use and the Heroku guide doesn't mention this process.